# Missing $ insert in \lstlistoflistings because of caption with underscore

Tags: listings

I add code using this command

```latex
\newcommand*{\addcode}[2]{
    \lstinputlisting[caption={#1, (\detokenize{#2}.ml)}]{code/#2.ml}
}
```

Some of my `.ml` files contains underscores like `Two_Opt.ml`.

So when I call `\lstlistoflistings` I get some errors because latex understand my `_` indices and I get this result :
[image]
How can I make this work ?

MWE :

```latex
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\addcode}[2]{
    \lstinputlisting[caption={#1, (\detokenize{#2}.ml)}]{code/#2.ml}
}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcode{2-opt}{Two_Opt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\protect` if using macro in a fragile command.

```
\begin{filecontents}{Two_Opt.ml}
some code...
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\addcode}[2]{
    \lstinputlisting[caption={#1, (\protect\detokenize{#2}.ml)}]{#2.ml}
}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcode{2-opt}{Two_Opt}
\end{document}
```